# Generating from an unknown discrete posterior distribution

Tags: self-study, prior, posterior, probability-generating-fn

My question is that if I have an informative prior with density 
$$f(N) \propto \frac{1}{N^2}$$
and posterior for N is
$$ P(N|T) \propto \big\{{n^A \choose T} {N-n^A \choose n^B-T}/{N \choose n^B}\big\} \times (1/N^2)$$
with $n^A=34, n^B=45, T=24$, how to generate samples from the above discrete unknown distribution? The final posterior quantiles for $N$ are:
$$q_{2.5\%}=57, q_{50\%}=64, q_{97.5\%}=78$$
And $N$ is population size. Are there any ideas to draw samples based on this density and receive these results? Thanks.

The example of R code that I tried is here. I did not try important-sampling since I was thinking if curve the distribution function and find the cdf and inverse it, we can get real generated N's. This is the code that I have tried. The logic should be true, and the inits values outside this range is 0. I tried to make the whole areas add up to 1 as you can see from "cumsum". Any suggestions? Or maybe I could try more sophisticated techniques.

> N <- rep(c(54:90),1540)  #init val
>
> f <- function(x){
>   (choose(34,24)*choose(x-34,21)/choose(x,45))*(1/(x^2)) }
>
> curve(f,55,100,xlim=c(50,100)) Z <- cumsum(f(N))
>
> Z[match(0.25,Z)] match(0.024,Z)
>
> match(quantile(Z,c(0.5)),Z) N[28490] #as e.g.

Comment: did you try to sum the unscaled posterior numerically? Then you would have a known posterior, and the invers distribution function algorithm can be used directly ...

Comment: Also, is this a self-study question?Then please add the self-study tag!

Comment: Yes, This is a self-studies. I accrossed the problem when I was reading an article. I have also tried the technique that you mentioned, but it did not give me  those quantiles.

Comment: Then, can you show us your work?

Comment: That is good, but you should really do that as an edit to your original post! It belongs there, and that way will be much more readable!

Comment: Do you really mean to have your N run from 54? When N is 54 your second choose term would be `choose(20,21)` ... !

Comment: This is a typo, as you can see in the third line I wrote 55. If someone really has an idea, I would appreciate to post. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your distribution?  What is the set of possible values of $N$ to which the formula for $P$ applies?

Comment: See, P is the sign for the pdf, which is posterior here. Everything is clear. When Posterior does not follow an exact form, we should use proportional sign. You could read a Bayesian book to become familiar with the concepts. N is population size and there where not other information for the N. But in order to understand how the area becomes 1, we should try trial-error kind of method.  Important sampling is tedious in this situation. But I am sure that they are other method such as

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some trial-error method, and I think this method could be good (however it is ad hoc,it works better than importance sampling). I have explained the method of solving based on cdf in the question.

The R code:

```
N <- rep(55:90,each=1540)
f <- function(x){  
(choose(34,24)*choose(x-34,21)/choose(x,45))*(1/(x^2)) }
curve(f,xlim=c(50,100)) 
Z <- cumsum(f(N)) 
summary(Z) data <- as.data.frame(cbind(N,Z)) 
View(data)
```